# Estimate the amount of time it takes to complete a programme in C#

Tags: c#, stopwatch

I am using Stopwatch and I would like to estimate how long it takes from start to finish.

It looks like a very simple complex. I instantiated stopwatch, start it, then stop it and then by writing a method .elapsed it should provide me with the time it takes from start to stop.

Unfortunately it always provides me with 00:00:00.

Do I have to set something specific to my culture on my PC or?

I have also tried .StartNew() but to no avail.

```
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();

        string juniorDevOpsFolder = "JuniorDevOps";
        string targetPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        int endIndex = targetPath.IndexOf(juniorDevOpsFolder);
        var juniorDevOpsPath = targetPath.Substring(0, endIndex + juniorDevOpsFolder.Length);
        string directory = "Files";
        string targetDirectory = Path.Combine(juniorDevOpsPath, directory);
        ProcessDirectory(targetDirectory);
        stopwatch.Stop();

        // Write hours, minutes and seconds.
        Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}", stopwatch.Elapsed);
```

Again, the output is 00:00:00

Comment: What is `ProcessDirectory` ??

Comment: This doesn't look like [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I call methods, but they are not relevant here, focus on the stopwatch part.

Comment: The method you call is very relevant as it seems to be faster than 1s. Which you ought to have noticed..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is taking less than one second to execute, so formatted `stopwatch.Elapsed` is printing 00:00:00 to console. Try `stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds` instead of formatted `stopwatch.Elapsed`.

something like

```
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();

    //Your business logic

    stopwatch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"Elapsed milliseconds : {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds}" );
```

Answer (score 1):

What about that code:

```
var watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();

        watch.Start();

        // do something what do you want

        watch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine($"Execution Time: {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
```

Comment: Thank you it was exactly elapsed milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

It probably takes less than a second. Try formatting for milliseconds.

Comment: This should be a comment. You aren't even sure ("probably") so an answer is not the correct choice. You can turn it into an answer after OP says that this was the problem. Also for this to be an answer you should also add _how_ to do what you suggest - either show code or link to some docs page.

Comment: Well, there's no way to be sure, because I don't know what ProcessDirectory does. But in all likelihood the issue is that it takes less than a second, because most lines of code take much, much less than a second. I suggested an answer - to format it differently since OP clearly knows how to format a TimeSpan object. And you dont need to use ElapsedMilliseconds, like the other answers would have you believe. The correct solution is to format Elapsed to show the ms part.

Comment: It is likely but not sure. A comment saying "It probably less than a second. Try to format it for milliseconds. __LINK TO FORMATTING__." Would be amazing. If OP then says this helped you should create an answer with the same content as the comment and include an example of a format-string for milliseconds. I don't know if I'm being too picky here but I just wanted to mention it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's just because your programm takes **less** than one second to execute and tha's why you get zero hours, zero minutes and zero seconds? Try unformatted output or `ElapsesMilliseconds` property

Comment: This should be a comment. You aren't even sure ("Maybe") so an answer is not the correct choice. You can turn it into an answer after OP says that this was the problem. Good thing you mentioned the `ElapsesMilliseconds` property but try to link to the docs in such a case - that's always really helpful. Also for the _unformatted output_ part, show an example :)